# Error while trying to set ffmpeg profile

Tags: ffmpeg

Ok, I have a feeling this might be a silly question, but I can't see what I am doing wrong. This is my command:

ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline output.mp4

and the error it returns is: "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"

I tried specifying the audio codec and using the other profiles, all to no avail... But the command works if I drop the -profile

Here is the log:

```
ffmpeg version N-78758-g5156578 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.100 / 57. 27.100
  libavformat    57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 37.100 /  6. 37.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : 7.1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '16BL3.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2016-12-16 09:39:01
    timecode        : 00:16:02;15
  Duration: 00:00:53.95, start: 0.557267, bitrate: 59879 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 8 channels, s32 (24 bit), 9216 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-16 09:39:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-16 09:39:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:16:02;15
    Stream #0:2(eng): Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) (xd5b / 0x62356478), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-16 10:23:54
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:16:02;15
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:2:2
[libx264 @ 0371fa00] Error setting profile baseline.
[libx264 @ 0371fa00] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444
Output #0, mp4, to 'bloco3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    timecode        : 00:16:02;15
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 29.97 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-16 10:23:54
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:16:02;15
      encoder         : Lavc57.27.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-16 09:39:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.27.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Any clue on what might be going on?

Comment: Great question and I'm surprised ffmpeg doesn't use a default pixel format for the baseline profile like it does with the high444 profile.

Answer (score 6):

Forget it. Posting this question made me pay more attention to the log: if anyone is interested the answer is that you have to specify the colour space - "-pix_fmt yuv420p" in my case. Sorry guys.

Comment: What's the default profile and colour space that's used if you don't specify either `-profile:v` or `-pix_fmt` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i did this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpg -i input.mp3  -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -c:s mov_text -strict experimental -vprofile baseline -level 2  -threads 0 out4.mp4
```